# Obtain whois data for a short domain name

Tags: php, domain-name, whois

Let say, we want to get a date of registration of a domain name. This information can be easily obtained from whois.crsnic.net server (on port 43). However, if we want to obtain that kind of information for a short domain like AAA.COM, chances are, the server will respond like this:

> Whois Server Version 2.0 Domain names in the .com and .net domains can
>   now be registered with many different competing registrars. Go to
>   http://www.internic.net for detailed information. AAA.COM.CN
>   AAA.COM.TW AAA.COM2.CN AAA.COM To single out one record, look it up
>   with "xxx", where xxx is one of the records displayed above. If the
>   records are the same, look them up with "=xxx" to receive a full
>   display for each record. ...

Obviously, it means that there are same domains with the same TLD base.
How can I get the record for AAA.COM in this case? I dont really understand what does following mean.

> To single out one record, look it up
>   with "xxx", where xxx is one of the records displayed above.

Right now, my query looks like this

```
$sp = fsockopen ("whois.crsnic.net", 43);
fputs ($sp, "aaa.com\r\n");
```

Comment: WHOIS servers are beasts to work with.  I suggest you study the code here: https://github.com/rfc1036/whois .. It took me about 4 hours to write a barely working WHOIS client in PHP.  You must be prepared for recursive queries to get all the appropriate information and deal with wildly varying formats between servers.

Comment: Note that your problem is not related anyway to the length of your domain names. It is just related to the fact that there are nameservers registered with the same prefix as your domain name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you send `=aaa.com`, you'll get a response that includes the following:

```
   Server Name: AAA.COM.CN
   Registrar: MELBOURNE IT, LTD. D/B/A INTERNET NAMES WORLDWIDE
   Whois Server: whois.melbourneit.com
   Referral URL: http://www.melbourneit.com

   Server Name: AAA.COM.TW
   Registrar: MELBOURNE IT, LTD. D/B/A INTERNET NAMES WORLDWIDE
   Whois Server: whois.melbourneit.com
   Referral URL: http://www.melbourneit.com

   Server Name: AAA.COM2.CN
   Registrar: XIN NET TECHNOLOGY CORPORATION
   Whois Server: whois.paycenter.com.cn
   Referral URL: http://www.xinnet.com

   Domain Name: AAA.COM
   Registrar: NETWORK SOLUTIONS, LLC.
   Whois Server: whois.networksolutions.com
   Referral URL: http://networksolutions.com
   Name Server: WALDO.NATIONAL.AAA.COM
   Name Server: XB.NATIONAL.AAA.COM
   Status: clientDeleteProhibited
   Status: clientTransferProhibited
   Status: clientUpdateProhibited
   Status: serverDeleteProhibited
   Status: serverTransferProhibited
   Status: serverUpdateProhibited
   Updated Date: 20-may-2014
   Creation Date: 03-aug-1990
   Expiration Date: 02-aug-2019
```

This tells you that the appropriate whois server for `aaa.com` is `whois.networksolutions.com`. So you should retry using that server, and you'll get the details:

```
Domain Name: AAA.COM
Registry Domain ID:
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.networksolutions.com
Registrar URL: http://networksolutions.com
Updated Date: 2009-11-19T00:00:00Z
Creation Date: 1990-08-03T00:00:00Z
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2019-08-02T00:00:00Z
Registrar: NETWORK SOLUTIONS, LLC.
Registrar IANA ID: 2
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abuse@web.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.8003337680
Reseller:
Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited
Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited
Domain Status: serverDeleteProhibited
Domain Status: serverTransferProhibited
Domain Status: serverUpdateProhibited
Registry Registrant ID:
Registrant Name: The American Automobile Association, Inc.
Registrant Organization: The American Automobile Association, Inc.
Registrant Street: 1000 AAA Drive
Registrant City: Heathrow
Registrant State/Province: FL
Registrant Postal Code: 32746
Registrant Country: US
Registrant Phone: 407-444-7000
Registrant Phone Ext:
Registrant Fax:
Registrant Fax Ext:
Registrant Email: no.valid.email@worldnic.com
Registry Admin ID:
Admin Name: The American Automobile Association, Inc.
Admin Organization: The American Automobile Association, Inc.
Admin Street: 1000 AAA Drive
Admin City: Heathrow
Admin State/Province: FL
Admin Postal Code: 32746
Admin Country: US
Admin Phone: 407-444-7000
Admin Phone Ext:
Admin Fax:
Admin Fax Ext:
Admin Email: internet.operations@national.aaa.com
Registry Tech ID:
Tech Name: The American Automobile Association, Inc.
Tech Organization: The American Automobile Association, Inc.
Tech Street: 1000 AAA Drive
Tech City: Heathrow
Tech State/Province: FL
Tech Postal Code: 32746
Tech Country: US
Tech Phone: 407-444-7000
Tech Phone Ext:
Tech Fax:
Tech Fax Ext:
Tech Email: internet.operations@national.aaa.com
Name Server: XB.NATIONAL.AAA.COM
Name Server: WALDO.NATIONAL.AAA.COM
DNSSEC: not signed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help.